# Why is my setState not updating the state or triggering re-render?

Tags: reactjs

```js
const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    let match = persons.filter(person => person.name === newName)
    if (!(match.length > 0 && window.confirm(`${newName} is already added to phonebook, replace the old number with a new one?`))) {
      let newPerson = {name: newName, number: newNumber, id: persons[persons.length - 1].id + 1}
      ContactServices
        .create(newPerson) //this is a function linked to API to update the phonebook
        .then(response => {
          setPersons(persons.concat(response))
          setFilterPersons(persons)
          setNewName('')
          setNewNumber('')
          //the four setState above does not work but setMessage works
          setMessage(`new number ${newPerson.name} is added`)
          setTimeout(() => {
            setMessage(null)
          }, 5000)
        })
    }
//...rest of the code
```

I'm having problems figuring out why only some of my setStates don't work. `setMessage` works but not `setPersons` or `setNewName`. I tried passing in a function instead a new object into setState, and `console.log` within the callback function. It worked so it seems that the function is executed but the new state is just not saved? I cannot use `useEffect` in a callback function here either.

Comment: try this ---> `setPersons(() => persons.concat(response))`

Answer (score 0):

change this condition to something meaningful for javascript this condition always returns false so your code inside ** if ** never works

```
window.confirm(`${newName} is already added to phonebook, replace the old number with a new one?`)){
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the state in React acts like an async function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and put a `console.log` right after it, it runs before the state has actually finished updating.

Which is why we have `useEffect`, a built-in React hook that activates a callback when one of it's dependencies have changed.

**Example:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
   // Should show updated state -
   console.log(state);
}, [state])
```

The callback will run only after the state has finished changing and a render has occurred.

**Note:** "state" in the example is interchangeable with whatever state piece you're dealing with in your case, be it `persons` / `newName` / `newNumber` etc..

Comment: Also, just as a general recommendation, try to avoid having multiple state pieces like this, and instead work with a single or few state objects that combine those pieces. Not a MUST, but is generally cleaner, easier to follow, and prevents the need to have so many `setState` functions one after another.